# how to overlay html on 3d canvas?

Tags: html, forms, input, overlay, three.js

I need to everlay an html form on the 3D scene(three.js)

```
<FORM NAME="test">
<P>Enter your  Name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="firstName"><BR><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="Button" Value="Name" onClick="functionInput(this.form)">
</P>
</FORM>
```

it just appear hiden, what can I do?

Comment: `form {position:absolute; z-index:999} formParent{position:relative}`

Comment: aparently it was not drawing the elements becouse of this line of code:...  renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );..now the form appears but I cannnot type anything in it

Comment: Are you using some mouse events on canvas? Try to comment them and check if you will be able to type.